# Some packets are dropped in [wan-local], when DNAT rule exists

Tags: iptables, dnat

I am running EdgeOS (aka vyatta 6.3 aka debian) with 3.4.27.
There are two DNAT port forwarding rules like this:

```
rule 1 {
 destination {
     port 65432
 }
 inbound-interface eth0
 inside-address {
     address 192.168.88.5
 }
 log disable
 protocol tcp_udp
 type destination
}
```

Disregarding specifics of this linux distribution I assume that ALL TCP and UDP packets should be forwarded to LAN and only filtered by [wan-lan] firewall rules.
Am I right in this assumption?
Because *some* packets designated to IP of eth0 and with dport satisfying DNAT rule, are still end up in [wan-local] firewall.
Those packets are mostly TCP with following flags: ACK RST, RST, ACK FIN. Flow is not really active and there are no drops on eth0 during that time.

Am I missing something or iptables does not do its job 100% properly?

Thank you.